# Using jQuery/JavaScript to generate meta description and keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta-tags

I want to include a javascript/jquery script in my page that will automatically generate Meta description from the content of a specific element. But i have no clue where to start from. Can someone here guide me through this?

Comment: Why? The primary audience (search engines) won't execute the JavaScript, and the content (presumably) depends on nothing that only the client knows, so you could do it server side anyway.

Comment: if you are thinking about crowlers i think you are doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as creating a new meta tag, setting it's name attribute and it's value attribute to the content of the element targetted

```
$('<meta />').attr({
  name: 'description',
  value: $('#idOfElementWidthDescriptionContent').text()
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Just to repeat what the other said: This will do absolutely nothing useful. Search engines can't read it, nor do browsers do anything worthwhile with it.

Comment: Search engines are starting to process javascript, the amount supported is however not well known so indeed it is best to avoid JS, for now, when it comes to SEO